# Doing a delayed image swap in responsive css platform (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to figure out how to do a simple fade in of image2 over image1 in the code below.  Normally I would use css with position: absolute and z-index to place image1 on top of image2 and then fade out image1 to reveal image2.  Problem is I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap responsive css which seems to preclude this and similar easy methods, so I turned to jQuery.  But I can't seem to get the coding right.  What I'm using below only shows a split second of image1 before loading image2.  This is also only part of what I want it to do.  Once I have the delayed image src change, I would like to fade in the new image.  I have tried putting image2 in the containing div background-image, but couldn't get the responsive css to treat it correctly.  So I'm not sure what else to try. Could someone point me in the right direction please? I can only seem to find methods for CSS effects.

in html file:

```
<img class="contactus" src="/responsive/images/image1.jpg" />
```

in javascript file:

```
$(".contactus").delay(3500).attr("src", "/responsive/images/image2.jpg");
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're changing the src, unless you preload the images, you would need to use `$(".contactus").on('load', function(){...});` so that any animation doesn't happen before the new image has loaded.

Comment: You could do something like this: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SaTva/)

Comment: @Popnoodles-forgot to indicate the the js is wrapped in $(document).ready(function()

Comment: @ilias-in the Twitter Bootstrap environment, the second image is placed below (height axis) the first. So while the images switch the second image moves up the page to where the first faded out.

Comment: I changed the positioning of the images, they now stack on top of each other [new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SaTva/1/).

Comment: @ilias-still can't get it to work in responsive css environment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is it just switches the image without any effects. Try layering the images on top of one another, hide the second image and then fade it in over the top of the first. Once it's faded in, then hide the first image (optional). Haven't tested the following but it should set you in the right direction.

HTML:

```
<div><img class="image1" src="/responsive/images/image1.jpg" />
<img class="image2" src="/responsive/images/image2.jpg" /></div>
```

JS:

```
$(".image2").hide().delay(3500).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $(".image1").hide();
});
```

CSS:

```
div { position: relative; }
img { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;  }
```

Comment: @hotdigity-this is close to something I have already tried.  The absolute positioning caused problems with the responsive css.  But I will try it again since your JS is slightly different.

Comment: @hotdigity-this doesn't work properly in responsive css environment.  Looks ok until delay fires, then both images are visible (one above the other vertically) then the top image disappears as the fade in of the bottom image proceeds and the bottom image moves up to replace the position of the top image.

Comment: It's hard to say given so many other factors at play with Bootstrap css. You'll need to try replicate the issue with Bootstrap code and post it here.